# Exporting PDF from Adobe Illustrator without aliasing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, anti-aliasing

I am working with an image with an aliasing problem in Adobe Illustrator CS6.  The aliasing disappears after unchecking `Preferences-> General -> Anti-aliased Artwork`.

However, when I export the file as a PDF, the aliasing returns when viewed with Adobe Acrobat.  Once again, in Acrobat, by unchecking `Edit-> Preferences... -> Page Display -> Rendering -> Smooth line art`, the problem disappears.

The same is the case for any PDF-viewer.  Is there a way, in Adobe Illustrator, to remove the aliasing problem, rather than just temporarily hide it?  I wish to send my PDF to an associate without having to say, "you will need to change your PDF-viewer preferences in order for the figures to look right".

Comment: I don't believe so. View settings are system independent and never saved with the actual document.

Comment: Not a definitive answer but, if the art does not have to be vector, then you could consider rasterizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifacts like this come about because the application (Illustrator or Acrobat) is creating a pixel rendering of the vector object on the fly, based on the resolution of your monitor, the relative size of the preview and the settings in the application being used to view it.

It's inherent in the way the rasterization works, and short of printing out a proof copy rather than viewing on-screen, this will always be a factor when viewing vector objects on a low-resolution device. You will have to tell your associate to adjust settings.